# Line terminator getting added to plain text file

Tags: line, newline

I'm a little confused by some behavior I'm seeing with text files on my Mac. When I open a new file in vim and type in a single character (let's say the letter "t") into the file with no carriage return and hit save and then do a hex dump on the file (using vim's `:r !xxd` command), I see the following:

`00000000: 740a                                     t.`

There is still a line feed `oa` in the file. And when I look at the file properties on the file, there are two bytes, not one. How did it get in there if I didn't type it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out vim automatically adds a newline character at the last line to comply with Posix standard that all lines must end with a new line. You can turn this off with `:set noeol` in vim.